# How to create Telegram Stickers programatically in Android application

Tags: java, android, chat, telegram

I want to build an Android app that gets a group of images and should make a telegram sticker pack of it. I know how to create sticker by @stickers bot. But I want to do it automatically. 
What Should I do and what is the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bots can't communicate with other bots, you should take a look at Telegram CLI Api. Or with your bot send stickers to your own account and then forward them to stickers bot.

Comment: Is it anyway to do it with my android app?